# renderizado condicional en el fetch

Tags: reactjs, fetch, alert

Estoy realizando un register. Cuando el usuario ya existe la API me devuelve un error 409. La idea es mostrar un alert cuando el usuario ya existe o navegar a la página registered cuando el usuario se crea exitosamente y ahí mostrarle al usuario el teamID generado con uuidv4.

He logrado que me muestre el alert cuando el usuario ya existe, el problema es que también navega hacia registered y me muestra que el teamID es undefined.

Quisiera que cuando el usuario ya existe sólo me muestre el alert, pero no pude lograr que funcione.

Este es mi código:

```
const onSubmit = () => {
    const teamID = !values.teamID ? uuidv4() : values.teamID;

    fetch(`${REACT_APP_API_URL}/auth/register`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            user: {
                userName: values.userName,
                password: values.password,
                email: values.email,
                teamID: teamID,
                role: values.role,
                continent: values.continent,
                region: values.region,
            },
        }),
    })
    .then((response) => {
        if(!response.ok) {
            Swal.fire({
                icon: "error",
                title: "El usuario ya existe!",
                text: "Por favor intente nuevamente con otro nombre de usuario."
            });
        } 
        response.json();
    }) 
    .then((data) => {
        navigate("/registered/" + data?.result?.user?.teamID);
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Problema

Con respecto a:

> me muestra que el teamID es undefined.

Uno de los problemas es que estás devolviendo `undefined` en el primer `then`:

```javascript
fetch(`${REACT_APP_API_URL}/auth/register`, {
  // ...
    })
    .then((response) => {
        if(!response.ok) {
            Swal.fire({
                icon: "error",
                title: "El usuario ya existe!",
                text: "Por favor intente nuevamente con otro nombre de usuario."
            });
        } 
        response.json(); // Aquí no estás devolviendo nada, te falta el return
    }) 
    .then((data) => {
        navigate("/registered/" + data?.result?.user?.teamID); // Aquí data es undefined porque en el then anterior devolviste undefined
    });
 }
```

### Explicación

Recuerda que los `then` de las [promesas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#encadenamiento) se encadenan, y el `then` siguiente recibirá como parámetro el valor devuelto por el `then` anterior (A menos que se arroje una excepción, la cual la deberías manejar con un `catch`)

Por lo tanto si tienes por ejemplo varios `then` encadenados, debes asegurarte de siempre devolver un valor dentro de la arrow function que tienes o por lo menos arrojar una excepción:

```js
async function fetch() {
  return Promise.resolve("respuesta");
}

function main() {
  fetch()
    .then((respuesta) => {
      console.log("Respuesta1 : ", respuesta);
      return respuesta + " 2"; // Devuelvo un valor 
    })
    .then((respuesta) => {
       console.log("Respuesta 2: ", respuesta);
       respuesta + " 3";  // Aquí no estoy devolviendo nada, ergo, estoy devolvieno undefined 
    })
    .then((respuesta) => { // Aquí el valor es undefined
      console.log("Respuesta 3: ", respuesta); // Undefined
    });
}

main();
```

Si ejecutas el ejemplo, podrás ver que el segundo `then` no devuelve nada porque no tiene `return` y el tercer `then` muestra `undefined` al loguear el valor, que es lo que te está pasando.

### Solución

En resumen, para solucionar el problema del valor `undefined` debes devolver un valor en tu primer `then`:

```javascript
fetch(`${REACT_APP_API_URL}/auth/register`, {
  // ...
    })
    .then((response) => {
        if(!response.ok) {
            Swal.fire({
                icon: "error",
                title: "El usuario ya existe!",
                text: "Por favor intente nuevamente con otro nombre de usuario."
            });
        } 
        return response.json(); // Usamos return para devolver la promesa que se resolverá en el siguiente then
    }) 
    .then((data) => { // Esto se ejecutará siempre, ya sea que hayas mostrado o no el alert, porque no tienens ningún condicional para evitarlo.
        navigate("/registered/" + data?.result?.user?.teamID);
    });
 }
```

---

Por otro lado, con respecto a:

> He logrado que me muestre el `alert` cuando el usuario ya existe, el **problema es que también navega hacia registered**

Si quieres que cuando el usuario ya existe solo muestre el alert y **no** haga la redirección, una solución podría ser arrojar una excepción para no ejecutar el siguiente `then` y evitar la redirección. Esto sería:

```js
async function fetch(res) {
  return Promise.resolve(res);
}

function main() {
  fetch({response: {ok: false}})
    .then((respuesta) => {
      console.log("Respuesta: ", respuesta);
      if (!response.ok) {
        alert("Usuario ya existe");
        throw new Error("Usuario ya existe");
      }
      return fetch("data")
    })
    .then((data) => {
       console.log("Data: ", data);
       navigate(""); // Esto no va a ejecutarse debido a la excepción arrojada
    })
    .catch(error => {
       console.log("Error:", error) // Esto se ejecutará
    })
}

main();
```